# How does numpy/pandas index self-assignment work?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was experimenting with numpy when I noticed that:

```
x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
print(x)
x[[1,0]]=x
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]
[[0 1]
 [0 1]]
```

Similarly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,2],'y':[1,3]})
print(df)
df.iloc[[1,0]]=df
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   x  y
0  0  1
1  2  3
   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  1
```

Why?

Comment: You're pretty much assigning `x[0]` to `x[1]` and `x[1]` to `x[0]`, with no guarantee of what order these two operations are going to be happening.

Comment: Are you saying that the assignment is not atomic? Is this a bug?

Comment: adding to what @FrankYellin said, you can just add `.copy()` like `df.iloc[[1,0]] = df.copy()`. Same for `numpy` arrays.

Comment: So literally part of the assignment is completed before the entire assignment is complete?

Comment: Wow that's incredibly bad design! But you are correct. Thank you for answers.

Comment: Python doesn't make copies unless you tell it to. So it's essentially equivalent to `x[0] = x[1]; x[1] = x[0]` or vice versa.

Comment: Not really so much about python IMO so much as these libraries making the assignment op atomic by saving result in temporary variable or something.
But thanks again!

Comment: Numpy is used for very large arrays.  Temporary copies of any kind are evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy` does use buffering for things like `+=` (see `np.add.at` docs for ways around that).  But for simple assignment like this is doesn't.

`y[[1,0]] = y+0` is example of the buffering; the `y+0` produces a new array, which is then assigned.

For what it's worth, assignment is implemented as `y.__setattr__(idx, value)`.  That method does not test that `value` is the same as `y` (or more generally a `view`).  It's up to you, the user, to be cognizant of such issues.

A generalization of your example is to assign a `view`:

```
In [99]: y=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [100]: y[[1,0]] = y[::-1,::-1]
In [101]: y
Out[101]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

`y[::-1,::-1]` is a new array, but a view, sharing the underlying data-buffer with `y`.  So assignment of `y` ends up modifying this view incrementally.

Making a copy avoids that:

```
In [102]: y=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [103]: y[[1,0]] = y[::-1,::-1].copy()
In [104]: y
Out[104]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [3, 2]])
```

More often I've seen questions about a double assignment like this:

```
In [106]: y[0],y[1] = y[1],y[0]
In [107]: y
Out[107]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

Again, `y[1]` is a view of `y`, so gets changed during the assignment.

The correct switching assignment is:

```
In [108]: y=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [109]: y[[0,1]] = y[[1,0]]
In [110]: y
Out[110]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [0, 1]])
```

People try [106] because list equivalent does work:

```
In [111]: y=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [112]: alist=y.tolist()
In [113]: alist[0],alist[1] = alist[1],alist[0]
In [114]: alist
Out[114]: [[2, 3], [0, 1]]
```

List users, on the other hand, are often bitten by replicated references, as in:

```
In [125]: alist = [[1,2]]*3
In [126]: alist
Out[126]: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
In [127]: alist[0][1] = 4
In [128]: alist
Out[128]: [[1, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]
```